# c# can I use a while loop to continue reading a file until string is found?

Tags: c#, search

I want to search 3 files sequentially but I only need to find string in one file (file1,file2,file3)

Can I use something like

```
string string1, string2, string3, searchBox;

StreamReader file1, file2, file3;

file1 = File.OpenText("data1.dat");
file2 = File.OpenText("data2.dat");
file3 = File.OpenText("data3.dat");

string1 = file1.ReadLine();
string2 = file2.ReadLine();
string3 = file3.ReadLine();

searchBox = searchTxtBox.Text;

while(string1 != searchBox)
{
file1.ReadLine()
}
MessageBox("Results are" + string1 + string2 + string3);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can try something like this for each file (I am showing for one file):

```
string line;
file1 = new StreamReader("data1.dat");

while((line = file1.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   if(line.Contains(searchbox))
   {
      break;
   }
}

file1.Close();
```

Comment: thank you this is actually very clear to understand!

Comment: I tried this way into my window form and it worked!  but the second and third files still returned with the first string in them instead of following the same line as the first one, do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: do you want to check in the second and third files for the same 'searchbox' string? or something else??

Comment: No, the second and third files should read on the same line as the first one.  Example: if file1 contains Diablo1 in the third line, it should read the third line from file 2 and file 3.  The 3 files are sequentially read

Comment: i see, in such case you'll initialize a variable called int lineNo=0; inside the while loop for file1, you'll first crease that variable by one. For second and third files, you'll need another variable which will start from 0, it will also increase inside the while loop before if, the if will check whether that variable is equal to 'lineNo'. makes sense?

Comment: yes thank you very much! I will get to it asap and I will let you know how it turned out.

Comment: I can do all of this in the while loop for the file1 or I need to make new for file 2 and 3?

Comment: you'll need to make new while loops for each file

Comment: what exactly do I have to set the while loops for file2 and file3 since file1 is already taking care of the search? sorry for confusing

Comment: something like this for each file:   file2 = new StreamReader("data2.dat");
int lineNoFile2 = 0;
while((line = file2.ReadLine()) != null)
{   lineNoFile2++;
   if(lineNo==lineNoFile2)
   {//This is your desired line for file 2
      break;
   }
}

file2.Close();